# HTTP GET request failed in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, get, httpresponse

My attempt to get a response fails  a with status code 400 (bad request).

Here is the code I am using:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
            String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + pass));
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(
```

The authentication part of the code works fine, because earlier when I used

`request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username,password);`

I was  getting a status code 401 (unauthorized access error). but now i am not getting an authentication error but i am getting a 400 (bad request).

Comment: Try using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes.GetBytes` instead.

Comment: thanks but that didn't work either